# Are ILS CAT IIIA minimums based on the radar altimeter or on barometric altitude?

Tags: ils

[image]

From what I understand the CAT II ILS minimums on the far right are based on radar altimeter 102'AGL and barometric altitude DA(H) 429'MSL (100'ATL).

But what about the CAT IIIA minimums in the middle? What is DH50' based on? Above threshold level or above ground level?

Comment: On the CAT II it says DA (decision altitude) 429ft. D(H) (decision height) (100ft). I think one can assume from this that the DH (decision height) for CAT IIIA is height above ground. But don't take my word for it, I only fly flight simulators as a hobby :)

Comment: Looks like it does.  "Decision Height" is a radio altitude value.  "Decision Altitude" is a barometric altitude value.